# Uniqueness of Holomorphic 1-Forms

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds

As I understand it, a holomorphic differential on a torus (the Riemann surface for $w^2 = z(z-1)(z-\lambda)$ where $\lambda \neq 1$) is a form $\omega$ that can be written as $\varphi(t) dt$ where $\varphi$ is holomorphic, and it turns out $\varphi$ is also non-vanishing. The proof I am currently aware of (as sketched in lecture) is as follows: say we have another holomorphic differential $\varphi'(t) dt$. Then, by considering the quotient of these forms, we obtain an entire holomorphic function, which by Liouville is constant.

But my question is: is the step involving division allowed? And if not, what is a more precise way to formulate it?

Comment: You said "non-vanishing".

Comment: What is important about the "non-vanishing" part?